# Trouble getting my button to call my class

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Form application.  What this application does, is let the user browse to a drive/folder they wish to have files renamed for.  This app renames files that have "invalid" characters (that are defined in a RegEx pattern).

What i want to happen here is, after the user decides which drive/folder to use, a datagridview pops up showing the user files in the drive/folder that are going to be renamed.  The user then clicks a button to actually rename the files.  I'm having trouble though getting the code for my button in DriveRecursion_Results.cs set up.  Can anybody help me?  Code plz -- i'm extremely new to this and need syntax to look at to understand.

Form1 code:

```
namespace FileMigration2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderSelect("Please select:");

    }

    public string FolderSelect(string txtPrompt)
    {
        //Value to be returned
        string result = string.Empty;

        //Now, we want to use the path information to population our folder selection initial location
        string initialPathDir = (@"C:\");
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(initialPathDir);
        FolderBrowserDialog FolderSelect = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FolderSelect.SelectedPath = info.FullName;
        FolderSelect.Description = txtPrompt;
        FolderSelect.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        if (FolderSelect.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string retPath = FolderSelect.SelectedPath;
            if (retPath == null)
            {
                retPath = "";
            }
            DriveRecursion_Results dw = new DriveRecursion_Results();
            dw.Show();
            dw.DriveRecursion(retPath);

            result = retPath;

         }

        return result;

    }





    }
}
```

DriveRecursion_Results.cs code:  [the button is in here that i need help with!]

```
namespace FileMigration2
{
 public partial class DriveRecursion_Results : Form
{
    public DriveRecursion_Results()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void DriveRecursion(string retPath)
    {
        //recurse through files.  Let user press 'ok' to move onto next step        
        // string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(retPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        string pattern = " *[\\~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+ *";
        //string replacement = "";
        Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);

        string[] fileDrive = Directory.GetFiles(retPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        List<string> filePath = new List<string>();


        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        try
        {
            foreach (string fileNames in fileDrive)
            {

                if (regEx.IsMatch(fileNames))
                {
                    string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileNames);
                    string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNames);

                    DataGridViewRow dgr = new DataGridViewRow();
                    filePath.Add(fileNames);
                    dgr.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                    dgr.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
                    dgr.Cells[1].Value = fileNameOnly;
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgr);
                    filePath.Add(fileNames);
                }

                else
                {
                    DataGridViewRow dgr2 = new DataGridViewRow();
                    dgr2.Cells[0].Value = "No Files To Clean Up";
                    dgr2.Cells[1].Value = "";
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(retPath + "ErrorLog.txt");
            sw.Write(e);

        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //What do i type in here to call my FileCleanUp method???
    }




}
```

SanitizeFileNames.cs code:

```
namespace FileMigration2
{
   public class SanitizeFileNames
{

    public static void FileCleanup(List<string>filePath)
    {
        string regPattern = "*[\\~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+*";
        string replacement = "";
        Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);


        foreach (string files2 in filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(files2);
                string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
                string sanitizedFileName = regExPattern.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
                string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFileName);
                //write to streamwriter
                System.IO.File.Move(files2, sanitized);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
            //write to streamwriter

            }

        }

        }

    }
}
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the problem just calling a static method?

Comment: well here's the thing.  i want to call filePath from my DriveRecursion method--but i'm unsure how to.  I need to pass that into my button so that it knows to do a filecleanup on filepath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
 public partial class DriveRecursion_Results : Form {
    List<string> filePath;
```

and in driveRecursion method, just use

```
filePath = new List<string>();
```

and in the action button method, why don't you do

```
  if(filePath != null)
        SanitizeFileNames.FileCleanup(filePath);
```

1. You call `filePath.Add` twice ?
2. Your '`else`' is in the wrong place too.
3. What is `dgr2`?

Comment: i debugged this and it made little sense to me to declare filePath in Main.  It remained null.  The point of filePath is to provide the path for the FileCleanup so that it may rename files.  

As for dgr2 -- it is another instance of my datagridview.  i'm not sure if this was necessary but i have it there in case there is nothing to clean up in the drive/folder the user specifies.

Comment: You have to declare filePath as a class member, as I have written above. The reason for this is, you are creating the list at one time, and you are doing the actual cleanup at a different time (when the button is pressed). Therefore the data has to be stored somewhere persistent in the meantime. 

If it remains null, this is either because you have not set it in the DriveRecursion() method, or you perhaps declared it twice.